# Sorting tables alphabetically in Mapinfo Professional 10

Tags: mapinfo, sorting

I have appended one table to another, and now they are not sorted alphabetically. Is there any way to resort the table so that it is in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an SQL Select and then saving the query result as a new table. It should look something like this:

[image]

The sort will default to ascending order, if you want it descending add "Desc" after the column name in the 'Order By...' field.

Comment: Great, can you please mark it as the accepted answer so that others can benefit if they have a similar question.

Comment: Please also note that by default a table is not sorted. It might appear so but the sort order is not guaranteed. You can sort you table using the SQL Select shown above or you can sort the table when it's viewed in a browser in MapInfo Pro using the Sort option on the individual columns.

Comment: At the top left of my answer there should be a button to mark as answer (below the up and down voting buttons).